# How to get button default style under windows 10?

Tags: wpf

Looking to my first steps with WPF on Windows 7 I was very pleased. Seeing it on Windows 10 I was very surprised. The buttons didn`t looks like expected. Trying it with WinForms results in the expected look an feel.

Here my problem:

[image]

So my question:

How can I get the "normal" style of the default button (OK has IsDefault=true) with the expanded blue border for the button even when it has focus, without defining the button-style myself?
This is very important in case of setting the focus to the Cancel-button    programmatically, because in this case the dotted border will not be displayed, so on Win 10 the user can not know witch button will be pressed by `enter`.

Answer (score -1):

You can get similar button styles using Windows UWP.

In WPF, you can check out the [Modern UI(MUI)](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31) in MSDN site.

It can produce similar results. I have been working with mui for a couple of months and it really helped me to satisfy my client who wanted to have a Windows 10 like UI experience. I had to create tiles like in start menu also. MUI did a great job for me.

Get the MUI from Github. [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)

Also I had tried [devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/) and [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx) controls. Have a look at them too.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting links.  My windows application should run on windows from version 7 to 10. It should look on each version of windows as much as possible like other applications on this windows version and that without great effort.

Comment: Are you saying about the same UI looks or are you trying to say that the UI should look according to each operating system?
If you use MUI, it will help you to make a windows 10 like looks for your application. If it’s the same application that you’re loading in any other OS, it will have the same look for the UI as you have designed it.

Comment: I mean, that the same application, that will be executed in different windows OS versions should look according to the OS it is running on.  - I'm sorry for not explaining it understandable.

Comment: What you’re saying is not possible to be achieved by using any custom controls or tools. The only possible to do that is to create themes for different os and store it in the ResourceDictionary. Now get the `OSVersion` from `Environment Class`(refer MSDN), and set the theme accordingly.

Comment: For any custom controls this is clear. But for buttons and all the other basic wpf controls (textbox, checkbox, ...) I've supposed to get it out of the box and that is originally my question.

Comment: For default controls also if you need to have specific style you need to define them as Windows 10 doesn't display blue border around buttons by default.